# Is it possible to register and log in my users with the Soundcloud API as opposed to just connecting to it?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, registration, soundcloud

Basically, I'd like my users to be able to register and log into my site using their Soundcloud accounts (much like Google or Facebook). 
But I'm following the login flow from their docs (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication), and I understand how to redirect them to the Soundcloud connect screen to authorize my app. And from that, I get a code that I can exchange for an access token. But after that the docs state this:

> You should now store the access token in a database. Associate it with
>   the user it belongs to and use it from now on instead of sending the
>   user through the authorization flow.

So they're assuming that I already have registered users who then connect to Soundcloud through some other function of my app. But what I want, is for them to be able to create their account from their Soundcloud user info. I think this is initally possible, but when they return to log in again, I need that access token to identify them. But I can't get that access token without sending them through the auth flow again.

I'm guessing what I want to do can't be done, but it's also possible I'm overlooking something. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with IMGUR OAuth2 API. After you get the access token, make a new request to their [/me](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#me) endpoint. This way, you'll have the SoundCloud id for that particular user. Now you can check if you already saved this user in your database. If you have, just save the new token to make sure this user has granted your app access to their SoundCloud. I'm not sure if I were clear enough. Let me know if you need any further help .